# how to integrate rocket.Chat server in Single Page Application

Tags: rocket.chat

How to create **Chat Server** using rocket chat in our single page application, my services are in **Java** and front and is in **AngularJs** ,**Html**
and i have **MongoDb** for the database.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.